# Looping full page structure

Tags: wagtail

I am looking to create a page that will show almost like a table of contents, but I am having issues figuring out how to display this in the template. My structure might look something like this:

```
Story/
    Section 1/
        Chapter 1/
        Chapter 2/
    Section 2/
        Chapter 3/
        Chapter 4/
```

How can I get Wagtail to display all the sections and their respective chapters on the page?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are your sections / chapters defined at the moment? Individual pages, StreamField blocks, headings within a rich text field, or something else...?

Comment: hello, they are defined as basic pages with a heading and richtext fields. please see my models.py for a better idea:

Comment: `class Story(Page):
         parent_page_types = ['StoryIndexPage']
        subpage_types = ['StorySection', 'StoryChapter']
        further_information = RichTextField(blank=True)
        story_pinned = models.BooleanField()`